# Что это за запись в условии?

Tags: c++

Есть такой отрывок кода:

```
std::string successL;
std::string errorL;
std::string getupdate;

std::string LoginHash(std::string hash)
{
 for (int i = 10; i <= 25; i++)
{
    successL = "loginfound";
    errorL = "loginnotfound";
    getupdate = "getupdate";

    if (hash == successL.c_str(), successL.length())
        return successL;
    else if (hash == errorL.c_str(), errorL.length())
        return errorL;
    else if (hash == getupdate.c_str(), getupdate.length())
        return  getupdate;
}
 return false;
}
```

Я не совсем понимаю это условие:

```
if (hash == successL.c_str(), successL.length())
```

У нас сравнивается переменная hash типа string с переменной successL которую мы приводим к си строке.Но потом идет запятая и берется длинна строки successL.Что это за конструкция?Почему компилятор не ругается на запятую?

Comment: https://ravesli.com/urok-41-sizeof-zapyataya-i-uslovnyj-ternarnyj-operator/#toc-1

Comment: Откровенно говоря, странное условие. Потому что приоритет `==` выше приоритета запятой. Так что вычисляется значение `hash == successL.c_str()`, но `if` смотрит на результат выражения `successL.length()`, так что по логике эта функция *всегда* возвращает `successL`...

Comment: Выбросьте этот код, не читайте всякую ерунду...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`,` - это оператор, как `+` или `/`. `a, b` значит то же самое, что и `b`, за тем исключением, что левый операнд *вычисляется* перед правым (но в вашем случае это неважно, потому вычисление левого операнда ни на что не влияет).

Значит `if (hash == successL.c_str(), successL.length())` эквивалентно `if (successL.length())`, а это эквивалентно `if (successL.length() != 0)`. Как уже написали в комментах, у вас это условие всегда выполняется, так что `return successL;` всегда сработает на первой итерации.

Код - кривой и не работает.

Паучье чутье подсказывает мне, что там хотели написать что-то вроде `if (hash == СделатьХеш(successL.c_str(), successL.length()))`, где вместо `СделатьХеш` какая-то хеш-функция.